# How do I write commands that output (file) names with spaces to make them work within backticks?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Ever the lazy unix/linux command line user, I use quite a few little shell scripts to help me avoid typing.

For example, I have a script `lst` that prints the name of the most recent file in the current directory. If this is called `mytext` and I type `` emacs `lst` `` then `mytext` will open in emacs

However, if the most recent file is called `my text` then `` emacs `lst` `` will fail, as the shell interprets this command as `emacs my text` instead of `emacs my\ text`

Using quotes like in `` emacs "`lst`" `` corrects the problem, but uses a whopping two extra keystrokes

Is there any way to modify `lst` so that the command will work without the extra keystrokes? Outputting a backslash-escaped filename doesn't work.

I use `zsh`, but the problem (and hopefully the solution) is the same in `bash`

Comment: Create a script `els` that does ```exec emacs "`lst`"```; this saves you still more typing.  Or an alias (without the `exec`).

Answer (score 1):

[Never use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). You must always [quote properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). There are no shortcuts. `printf %q` is the only alternate that's remotely portable (Zsh's `${(q)var}` is similar), but these aren't a good fit for your problem. The correct (only) answer is to quote.

Edit: Maybe you should just stick with zsh for interactive things. I'm not an expert in that shell but I know for instance that it doesn't perform word-splitting or globbing in its default mode without using its special expansions.

```
$ zsh -c 'x="foo *"; echo $(printf "<%s> " $x)' # two passes of unquoted expansion
<foo *>
$ zsh -c 'emulate sh; x="foo *"; echo $(printf "<%s> " $x)'
<foo> <bltins> <builtins.mm> <COMPATIBILITY> <data> ...
```

This is a huge win for what you want (and is one of the big things that makes zsh totally incompatible with everything else script-wise). None of the other shells can do this.

Comment: I never use backticks in shell scripts. But the command line is something else - two identical keystrokes ` `  are far more economical than the three different ones in `$( )`

Comment: Oh god one character! But yes, golfers use it. Also `$[]` and some of the redirect shortcuts.

Comment: Yes, zsh doesn't split words when `sh_word_split` is unset, but this does't make any difference for the problem at hand

Comment: Why is that? Even if your `lst` script is written in bash, running it from zsh, emacs should only get one argument provided the Bash script is written correctly. (my "latest file" function is [here](https://gist.github.com/4029356) btw. Might be more complex than you need as it's meant to also pass around variable names safely.)

Answer (score 1):

How about keybinding your lazy function so you don't type anything, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and `zle` inserts the text for you right in your command line.

```
z_lst() {                                                                      
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extendedglob
  local lastfile
  # you could even implement your whole lst function here instead
  lastfile=$(lst)
  LBUFFER+=" ${lastfile// /\ }" # this should print the spaces like '\ '.
}                                                                               
zle -N z_lst && bindkey "^z" z_lst
```

Add this somewhere appropriate in your `.zsh`.